# Clickable Marked points on an Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dom

first check out the image for a better understanding of what I want to do. The red points on the picture will be clickable. When you click on them a description will pop up.

I saw the use of HTML `<area>` tag and a JS function with image coordinates.

Is there any ready made library available for this ?

[image: Roof Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best off making use of an `<img>` and the **[`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)** element. From here you can set `<area>` children with a circular `shape`, and specify the the co-ordinates. These are in the format `x,y` from the top-left pixel. With a circle, the third value is the diameter. You can link these off, or attach an event handler to display a popup:

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
}

area {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ZX6.png" usemap="#housemap">

<map name="housemap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="0,0,82,126" href="1.htm" alt="1">
  <area shape="circle" coords="190,58,30" href="2.htm" alt="2">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,30" href="3.htm" alt="3">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,30" href="4.htm" alt="4">
</map>
```

Comment: yes I have explored this solution. I was thinking maybe I can find a JS Library for this sort of stuff. But after a bit of searching I found no such thing.